# 03 Saturn ion engine won't start

Tags: engine, swap

03 Saturn replaced engine but when trying to start nothing happens. I have power to all the lights and gauges but when trying to turn the engine over it does nothing no sound or anything.

Also I had cut the white wire for the passlock fee years ago so I thought maybe I had to connect that again I did but it still did nothing.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Can you jump the starter relay to make the engine crank? Any codes?

Comment: When I jump the solenoid the starter spun and not sure about codes the scanner doesn't power on when I plug it in

Comment: Check your fuses theres either a dedicated dlc fuse or its powered off the power outlet fuse. Make sure the dlc has ground as well its one of the middle pins.

Comment: I will check that hopefully within the next couple days since car isn't at my house I can't go eight out and check but thanks for the advice